# Python Creating Dictionary from Excel Data (with tupels)

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from the values that I imported from an Excel file.

My code is as follows:

```
xl=pd.ExcelFile('KMeans_Test.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
Dict=df.to_dict()
```

In the Excel, the first column consists of x-coordinates, the second are y-coordinates.

I would like to create a dictionary looking like

```
Dict = {0:(x1,y2), 1:(x2,y2), ... , n(xn,yn)}
```

with the x- and y-coordinates being the respective coordinates from the Excel file.

Right now, the dictionary I get looks like this:

> Dict: {'Unnamed: 0': {0: 61, 1: 66, 2: 74, 3: 102, 4: 119, 5: 139, 6: 132, 7: 108, 8: 123, 9: 64, 10: 62, 11: 48, 12: 40, 13: 28, 14: 46, 15: 51, 16: 59, 17: 41}, 'Unnamed: 1': {0: 57, 1: 67, 2: 55, 3: 62, 4: 53, 5: 35, 6: 36, 7: 25, 8: 22, 9: 15, 10: 8, 11: 9, 12: 22, 13: 21, 14: 30, 15: 28, 16: 42, 17: 35}}

Anyone any idea how I can create the dictionary in the format that I want (with tuples within the dictionary)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use following manipulations:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('KMeans_Test.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
df.apply(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).reset_index(drop=True).to_dict()
```

First **apply** function changes the inner dict to tuples, then **reset_index** starts the index from 0 rather than 1.

Hope this helps!!